# TemplateView with forms - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Am having a challenge i hope you can help me over come.

Am building a django driven application for movie ticket bookings and coming up short on the forms.

When a user clicks on a particular movie, i want to render a page that has a form where the user can choose options for his/her ticket like number of tickets, seat number, date etc.

However, my form returns all movies in the database.

i want to be able to return the ONLY the movie the user has clicked on, seeing that this view already returns a particular movie clicked on by a user. How can i do this?

My current method gives me an `exception error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'`

In my forms.py i have this

```
class MoviePaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MoviePaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Movie.objects.get(slug=args[0]))
```

and in my views.py i have this

```
class SpecificMovieTemplateView(TemplateView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'movie.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        context = super(SpecificMovieTemplateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        context['movie'] = Movie.objects.get(slug=kwargs['movieslug'])
        print 'Movie ID is ==> ' + str(context['movie'].id)
        context['form_movie'] = MoviePaymentsForm(kwargs['movieslug'])
        return context
```

in my models.py i have this

```
class MoviePayments(TimeStampedModel):
    uuid_placement = shortuuid.encode(uuid.uuid4())
    short_uuid = uuid_placement[:8]
    reference_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True, unique=True,
                                        default="%s" % str(short_uuid))
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.ForeignKey(MovieShowDate)
    time = models.ForeignKey(MovieShowTimes)
    paid_for = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    mm_transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Comment: Paste Full Traceback . in which line you are getting error

Comment: Hey Allan, thanks for the prompt response. Please find here ==> http://dpaste.com/1766050/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Like Bogdan pointed out above, i needed to pass the slug field as an argument in the init method, and use filter on the queryset to return that particular movie like so

```
class MoviePaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MoviePaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['movie'].queryset = Movie.objects.filter(slug=slug)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are passing the movie_slug as first parameter to the form: 
`context['form_movie'] = MoviePaymentsForm(kwargs['movieslug'])` and first parameter to the form is the data dictionary. Modify the form like this:

```
class MoviePaymentsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, slug=None, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MoviePaymentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        movie = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Movie.objects.get(slug=slug))
```

Or  remove the argument from the args list like: `slug = args.pop(0)`

Comment: Hi Bogdan, thanks for your guidance, Though it did not work for me, it directed me towards the solution i was looking for which i have posted below